# Using Matplotlib in python gives bold font since upgrade

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using python to generate some plots. Since upgrading my matplolib, I have been having the issue of the font on the axes coming out as bold. I have no idea why. Also, my tick marks have stopped showing up, even though i have asked for them to be included. The color blue shows up as some weird type of blue, almost like teal In other words, a plot that used to display my graph with all the things that I have requested no longer gets saved or shown that way. Any ideas?

```
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))

    ax.plot(p_series,y_series,'b--',linewidth=0.5,label="test1")
    ax.plot(z_series,b_series,'k--',linewidth=0.5,label="test2")

    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(),rotation='horizontal')
    plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'white'
    plt.rcParams['axes.edgecolor'] = 'k'
    plt.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 0.5
    plt.tick_params(axis='both',which='both',direction='in')
    plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"
    plt.rc('xtick',labelsize=18)
    plt.rc('ytick',labelsize=20)
    plt.rc('axes',labelsize=20)
    ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=2)
    ax.tick_params(which='major', length=3)
```

Comment: Please provide some code/example output, we need this to answer your question properly (Any answer now would probably be a shot in the dark). What do you mean by tick marks?

Comment: I have followed your suggestion and added sample code.

Comment: Concerning color, the default color cycle has changed, see [colors-in-default-property-cycle](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colors-in-default-property-cycle). The font issue is more severe. It seems there is currently no good solution to it, just some hacky workaround, see [times-new-roman-font-is-always-bold](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/times-new-roman-font-is-always-bold/20608)